# API.AI - Using parameters to select next intent

Tags: android-intent, dialogflow-es, google-home

I'm creating a mock finance app in **API.ai**, and I need to get from the user which account they'd like. I have a default welcome `intent` as an entry, and a followup `intent` that collects what account they'd like (current, savings, etc).

How do I use the user response of "**current**" or "**savings**" parameters to choose the next `intent`?

Comment: FYI - Android Intents are an entirely different concept from API.AI intents.

Answer (score 0):

In API.AI you typically don't "choose" the next intent.  API.AI recognizes the user's intent using a machine model that is trained using the examples you give for each intent.

For your example I'd recommend using [API.AI's contexts](https://api.ai/docs/contexts) to signal to API.AI what intents should be you'd like to be matched after the user specifies their account type.  You can set an [outgoing context](https://api.ai/docs/contexts#output_contexts) for the intent which asks for the user's account type.  After this [outgoing context](https://api.ai/docs/contexts#output_contexts) is set the next match will strongly prefer intent that have a [input context](https://api.ai/docs/contexts#input_contexts) of the same value. this will behavior will continue for the lifetime of the intent ([more info on intent lifetime here](https://api.ai/docs/contexts#lifespan))

If you haven't already, you may want to setup a [fulfillment webhook](https://api.ai/docs/fulfillment) to validate that the user has said "savings" or "current" and hasn't matched this intent and then triggered another intent.  You can also set contexts in webhooks.